# Accidentally turn on SSL / HTTPS for phpmyadmin

Tags: php, ssl, phpmyadmin

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS, Apache 2.4.7, mysql 14.14, phpinfo.php

I was trying to reconfigure phpMyAdmin and I'm no longer sure what I actually did, because now all attempts to access the page result in a redirect to https, which doesn't work because my Apache server isn't configured to run SSL.  I go to http://MYDOMAIN/phpmyadmin and it turns it into https://MYDOMAIN/phpmyadmin/?collation_connection=utf8_general_ci&SID which just has an SSL connection error.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling phpMyAdmin several times with no success.

If I go to http://MYDOMAIN/phpmyadmin/setup I get a blank screen but this line shows up in my weblogs:

```
[Tue Mar 24 05:09:10.518308 2015] [:error] [pid 8888] [client 50.161.45.55:49637] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function PMA_generate_common_url() in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/common.inc.php on line 352
```

I've tried creating and uncreating /usr/share/phpmyadmin/config/config.inc.php but it seems to have no effect.

Any ideas what I might have done and how I can revert back?  mysql is still running fine and I'd rather not have to reinstall that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find phpmydmin's `config.inc.php` and change the line as follows:

`$cfg['ForceSSL'] = false;`

Comment: Ah, thanks.  This was the right thing, it was just in a directory I didn't expect:  `/var/lib/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`.  The file also appears in `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` and `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup/frames/config.inc.php`.  I had found the latter two but not the first.  Talk about confusing!

Comment: I don't have the file `config.inc.php` , but I've `config.sample.inc.php`

Comment: Usually you can copy `config.sample.inc.php` as `config.inc.php` and edit it accordingly. Refer to any readme document or to the comments within `config.sample.inc.php`